# "Silently" save canvas to image with javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have a canvas on which I draw pretty images!

Using .toDataURL('image/gif'), I save those images as image files. So far so good.

Thing is that I want to save a number of those images (I change parameters for each image to be saved.)

I would like to do it "silently", that is without having to click on "Save" on the modal window that pops up every time.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into the [download attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download) of an `<a>` tag? You could take the data URL from your canvas and place it as the `href` of an `<a>` tag, then set the `download` attribute as the filename. Then `click()` your link via JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `download` attribute of an `<a>` element, you can *silently* download the image data without needing to deal with any dialog windows. *I should warn that this could be **potentially dangerous** as it is literally downloading a file to your computer **without** any direct confirmation*.

Once you have your **data URL** from your canvas, the rest is pretty easy. You can create a new `<a>` element, set the `href` to your **data URL**, set the `download` attribute to the filename you wish to use, and then execute the `click()` event on this newly created element.

```js
let dataURL

const _Base64Image = url => {
  const img = new Image()
  img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous')
  img.onload = () => {
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas")
    canvas.width = img.width
    canvas.height = img.height
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0)
    dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
    _SetBG(document.querySelector("#imgTest"), dataURL, img.width, img.height)
  }
  img.src = url
}
const _SetBG = (el, data, w, h) => {
  el.style.width = `${w}px`
  el.style.height = `${h}px`
  el.style.backgroundImage = `url("${data}")`
}

const _SaveImage = (data, filename) => {
  const a = document.createElement("a")
  a.href = data
  a.download = filename
  a.click()
}

_Base64Image('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/99/Unofficial_JavaScript_logo_2.svg/2048px-Unofficial_JavaScript_logo_2.svg.png')

document.querySelector("input[type='button']").addEventListener("click", e => {
  _SaveImage(dataURL, "test_image.png")
})
```

```css
.random-background {
  max-height: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div id="imgTest" class="random-background"></div>
<br>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Save Image">
```

### NOTE

This snippet **will not work** on **StackOverflow** as part of their security settings. However I also uploaded this to [CodePen](https://codepen.io/EssXTee/pen/XWEQKPP) so you can see a working version.

For the sake of not forcing downloads on anyone I included a button that must be clicked to save the image. However this **is not required** for the code to work. Simply calling the `_SaveImage()` function (*and passing in the data URL and filename*) will work. But having the snippet do this automatically is somewhat problematic as you can get hit with multiple downloads for the same file just by going to the page.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer.

I have  tried your code verbatim and it does not solve my issue, since I still have to click on "Save" when the modal window "Save As" comes up.

What is it that I do wrong, then?

Comment: @Jean-PaulBardou My answer (like most answers on StackOverflow) is not a **copy/paste** solution. You will likely need to make small adjustments to make it work for ***your code*** (which is not included in your question). The reason I included a snippet (and CodePen link) is to show you that it does work (tested in Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and Opera). To make it work within ***your code*** I would need to see the part of it that currently saves the image to show you how *my code* should be integrated.

Comment: Your code--which as mentioned before I copied into an html file--worked perfectly as it was supposed to, no doubt about that.

Let's take your code as a starting point now,

Look at this constant declaration:

`const _SaveImage = (data, filename) => {
  const a = document.createElement("a")
  a.href = data
  a.download = filename
  a.click()
}`

My question is entirely about achieving that once the 'a.click()' instruction has been executed, the code saves the file **without**  asking me whether I want to do it.

Does that make sense now?

Thanks

Comment: @Jean-PaulBardou I'm afraid I don't understand. When you execute my `_SaveImage` function and pass in your data URL generated from your `<canvas>`, does it automatically download the file or is it still bringing up the save modal window? If so, it would appear there is either some specific browser setting affecting you (*have you tried in multiple browsers?*), or I would need to see some of your code to determine exactly what the issue is. This is why StackOverflow recommends you include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code

Comment: @EssTee: Use the very code you provided me with the first time! I ran it on Brave and indeed, it brings up the modal window asking me to confirm whether I want to save the image!

Comment: @Jean-PaulBardou Have you tried any other browsers? Browsers are allowed to control how files are downloaded and Brave (being a privacy focused browser) may restrict behavior like automatic downloads for certain file types. It's hard to really say at this point but this seems like this needs some troubleshooting to pinpoint the exact cause. I tested the code in 4 different browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and Opera) and it did not show a modal. If you try a different browser and it works, it means there is a setting/restriction in Brave doing this.

Comment: @Jean-PaulBardou After downloading Brave, it is a browser setting that is forcing the modal. **Settings -> Downloads -> "*Ask where to save each file before downloading*"**. JavaScript cannot ignore, overwrite or change browser settings so you will not be able to silently download files in the background if a user has that setting (or a setting like it) enabled.

Comment: Thanks @EssXTee, I have tried with some other browsers and sure enough, it works.

I'll just have to configure Brave to do it too!